# Typescript - get explicit object key type from an object defined with an index signature

Tags: typescript

Let's say the following object is created using the specified type definition. It must use the index signature `[key: string]` as the object is allowed to have any keys, or even no key at all.

```
interface CreateObject {
    [key: string]: {
        foo: string
        bar: number
    }
}

const myObject: CreateObject = {
    fooKey: {
        foo: "something",
        bar: 1
    },
    barKey: {
        foo: "something else",
        bar: 2
    }
}
```

Now, let's say I want to create a function that takes in a `key` parameter. The value of `key` should be equal to an actual key value within `myObject`, i.e. in the example above `key` should only ever be equal to `fooKey` or `barKey`.

```
interface SomeFunction {
    (key: keyof typeof myObject): void
}

const someFunction: SomeFunction = (key) => {
    console.log(myObject[key].foo)
}
```

This won't work as `keyof typeof myObject` is equal `[key: string]`, therefore as long as `key` in `someFunction(key)` is equal to any string then it won't have any type errors.

How do I ensure that only the actual keys within `myObject` can be passed in as the `key` parameter? For example:

```
someFunction("fooKey") // should pass
someFunction("barKey") // should pass
someFunction("notAValidKey"); // should fail
```

Here's a [Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJQnSB5ARgKwgTGQG8AoZK5AbQGsIBPALmQGcwpQBzAXVYrUhyGAHtRrDlxDdKwqrjhRWIAK4BbXNDlUAvuX3kEokB2TrGeQsVbpMOAkRIBeMjpHiA0kwHuhYiWQAIjZRdQgwAAseIIAaP2pFZWQARnddeKEk7xY3eSoA1hCwiOiZZAgAGzYIOISFJVYAJnSDcnJQSFhEFABlEoAxVRBiYBM86gAKBlyZ0RhkMEYABwh580tHYgBKVgA3UWAAEzajEzNQ8KGRsDGQVn6r4dHx12mmbeRnAD4JqmNTKJKhAAHSVUTcSYWKxOehMXgggLbU6XCDXF4gSZBAI5IKfAD0+PYkVEqkqR2QyzgbDY5FR6NuJix2SYeOQhOJpPJlOptPpz0ZmKCIFEYAAggA1OCVY647YAbnZRLYJLJFPgwEqQA) demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't widen the type of your object to your interface with an index signature. Once you do that it's impossible to know what keys are on your object or not.

If you still need to enforce the type of `myObject`, you can wrap it in an identity function that checks its type without widening it.

The `createObject()` wrapper is not strictly necessary, but makes the nature of the error easier to identify when it is generated at the instantiation rather than the usage of the object. If you remove the call to `createObject()` and introduce a typo into the definition of `myObject`, you'll still get an error but it will occur at its usage in the calls to `someFunction()`.

```
interface CreateObject {
    [key: string]: {
        foo: string
        bar: number
    }
}

function createObject<T extends CreateObject> (object: T) {
    return object
}

const myObject = createObject({
    fooKey: {
        foo: "something",
        bar: 1
    },
    barKey: {
        foo: "something else",
        bar: 2
    }
})

interface SomeFunction {
    <T extends CreateObject> (object: T, key: keyof T): void
}

const someFunction: SomeFunction = (object, key) => {
    console.log(object[key].foo)
}

someFunction(myObject, 'fooKey') // passes
someFunction(myObject, 'barKey') // passes
someFunction(myObject, 'notAValidKey') // fails
```

Comment: If I don't widen with type with an index signature then I have no type safety for `myObject`. For example, I could set `barKey: { oof: "something else" }` (misspelling) and it wouldn't detect any error.

Comment: I saw you edited your answer but I'm not sure how that fits into the code example.

Comment: OK I think I understand what you mean. Unfortunately, my real life example is a lot more complex than this and this solution won't work. To put it very simply, `const someFunction` is defined within a separate npm package I'm creating, and `myObject` is defined at the project root by the user. Therefore I need type safety as well as auto-completion/suggestions for `myObject` directly so that users receive warnings/errors if they try defining `myObject` incorrectly.

Comment: @GCM the `keyof typeof myObject` in your interface definition wouldn't be possible in that case anyway. How were you planning on defining that signature?

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble with. I'm importing the object using `fn` node.js package (although I might change to [cosmicconfig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cosmiconfig/)) then I want to get the actual key values from the object. Since `myObject` is separated from the rest of the package and can contain any keys, it needs its own type definition with `[key: string]` as the index signature. Sorry, I know this is changing my initial question and you answered what I initially asked so if nobody comes up with a better solution soon then I'll mark yours as correct.

Comment: @GCM I see what you want. [`createStyles`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-styles/src/createStyles/createStyles.d.ts) from material-ui was designed for a purpose very similar to this as well. I'll update my answer, but the user code will need to call this identity function to allow both kinds of type checks to be successfully performed.

Comment: Basically, the user creates `myObject`. They can also import `someFunction()` from the npm package. I want to ensure that 1) when they create `myObject` they can import a `CreateObject` type definition from a `.d.ts` file in `node_modules/myPackage/` so that the object is type checked correctly, and 2) when they use `someFunction(key)` they receive a type warning if `key` isn't a key within `myObject` they created.

Comment: This answer actually resolved _my_ problem. But I would love to not having to pollute the code with type specific stuff.

Do you know, if it is possible to create a type with keys based on XXX javascript object, but enforce their values? Without creating a function. 

So the same result as what `createObject()` creates but solely by using type definitions.

Comment: @Daniel [this?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChkLkBtAawnQC5kBnMKUAcwF0mzL-kMAPZCmrdiA7kBFbHChMQAVwC22aNIoBfUjtKhIsRCgDCUCHEgAeACoA+EpuRWAasggAPSCAAmzZPYAFABuTC4AlGG6pPrg0PBIyADKQioQAGJKIITAQiC2DnyUru5eEL7+9sghYQA0yDRMdOhCMMgRTMFCwD7RpAh5rMgI5pYQOPiETGYW1hgTBGAOALzIwcjLDsExAyBDKlh4ixvDo5ALhIFFFMJCANL0vE78t0wARMypEGAAFpxvtWelDkCmQAEYnFpAfwQQ9GI4ZDcRO9Pmlfpx3AAbZgQAFA2TyJgAJkhunCO0GRFRGSyOTyTBSaUy2TAuXy8yOhBW1WC9Ro4Q2hScu0+mIgADpMUIOCFaFxxbdyXpqcy6SBAgcLmB6gByW5wnUCgD0RuQAAc4MwccxSCraay8hrDpNtcgdbD6IbkCbzZbrbavqqHerNZzXTqQEIwABBFxwTE9A3G03wYDYoA)

Comment: @Daniel Notice in that example that `Create` and `SomeFunction` are not hard-coded to use the type `MyObject`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts more or less - beside that you also pollute the code with a function (`createObject`) just to make the types for TypeScript work which was what I initially tried to avoid :-D

Comment: @Daniel as I said before, the `createObject()` function isn't necessary here for type-safety, it just causes errors to highlight [at the instantiation of `myObject` where the typo is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dUBm.png) (assuming there is one), rather than [at the usage of `myObject`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gv8x.png), which is usually very tedious to debug.

Comment: I see. Maybe my question was not clear enough, but avoiding to create _function_ for that was what I tried to avoid, if that is possible. Like **having** this type-safety but only using TypeScript. Maybe I am looking for something that is not possible, I am not sure.

Comment: @Daniel again I refer you to [`createStyles`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-styles/src/createStyles/createStyles.d.ts). Using an identity function to prevent type widening is a very common pattern, and with something as generic as `interface Create<T> {
    <V extends T>(v: V): V
}`, you can use it to perform type checking on literally any type. If there was a way to do this without functions, large libraries like material-ui would definitely be using it instead, but there isn't.

Comment: Woops - sorry @PatrickRoberts, I was a bit confused here - I thought this was an answer on my post that I created afterwards :-) Maybe you can help there, where I added a bit more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013605/typescript-dynamic-object-keys-with-defined-values