# Typescript dynamic object keys with defined values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am encountering an issue trying to make typescript recognise the keys of a javascript object for me, while enforcing each key's value type because I want to create a typeof the keys of the object, so I can't just create a regular `type MyObject = { [key: string]: <insert type> }`.

Imagine an object `myobject` where I extract the keys of it like:

```js
const myobject = {
  foo: {},
  bar: {}
};

type MyObjectKeys = keyof typeof myobject; // 'foo' | 'bar'
```

How can I add type definitions to the values of the keys, while still being able to extract/inherit the definitions of the keys? If I do something like this, then I will no longer be able to extract the exact keys of the object, but only the type (string):

```js
type MyObject = { [key: string]: { value: boolean }}
const myobject = {
  foo: { value: true },
  bar: { value: false }
};

type MyObjectKeys = keyof typeof myobject; // string
```

I figured that I could achieve this by creating a helper function like:

```js
function enforceObjectType<T extends MyObject>(o: T) {
    return Object.freeze(o);
}
const myobject = enforceObjectType({
  foo: {},
  bar: {}
});
```

But I'd prefer to define a clear type for it, without having to pollute the code, writing functions only related to types. Is there a way to allow a set of strings as keys of a type without repetition?

The purpose of this is to get TypeScript to help pointing out the right object keys like (the real usage is a bit more complex, so I hope this describes it well enough):

```js
type MyObjectKeys = keyof typeof myobject; // string
function getMyObjectValue(key: MyObjectKeys) {
   const objectValue = myobject[key];
}

// suggest all available keys, while showing an error for unknown keys
getMyObjectValue('foo'); // success
getMyObjectValue('bar'); // success 
getMyObjectValue('unknown'); // failure
```

**Wrap up:** I want to define an object as const (in fact with `Object.freeze`) and be able to:

1. Extract the *exact* keys of the object (without having to type a definition of each key).
2. Define the type of each key, without overwriting the keys to `string` instead of what they are - like `'foo' | 'bar'`.

### Complete example

```js
type GameObj = { skillLevel: EnumOfSkillLevels }; // ADD to each key.
const GAMES_OBJECT = Object.freeze({
   wow: { skillLevel: 'average' },
   csgo: { skillLevel 'good' }
)};

type GamesObjectKeys = keyof typeof GAMES_OBJECT;

function getSkillLevel(key: GamesObjectKeys) {
  return GAMES_OBJECT[key]
}

getSkillLevel('wow') // Get the actual wow object
getSkillLevel('unknown') // Get an error because the object does not contain this.
```

In accordance to above, I can't do the following because that will *overwrite* the known keys to just any string:

```js
type GameObj = { [key: string]: skillLevel: EnumOfSkillLevels };
const GAMES_OBJECT: GameObj = Object.freeze({
   wow: { skillLevel: 'average' },
   csgo: { skillLevel 'good' }
)};

type GamesObjectKeys = keyof typeof GAMES_OBJECT;

function getSkillLevel(key: GamesObjectKeys) {
  return GAMES_OBJECT[key]
}

getSkillLevel('wow') // Does return wow object, but gives me no real-time TS help
getSkillLevel('unknown') // Does not give me a TS error
```

---

Another example: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hilleer/521b4cbcebbf487f5023cd81e936f4d6) for example and copy it to [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) if you want to change the code

Comment: I didn't understand it very well... Do you want a function that receives as parameters the keys of any given object? Or you want to set `myObject` as constant?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I will try to edit and express it better, but I basically just want to define the type of each key of `myobject` while still being able to "inherit" the keys dynamically.

Comment: Np, we are here to help you. Could you please post a complete example, of exactly what you want to happen?

Comment: Ok I have updated the question to include a more clear example of what I want to achieve. Let me know if I should create some sort of link to a playground for this.

Comment: So you want to "extend" the `GameObj` and the `getSkillLevel` to keeps just accepting the right keys, not just string, right?

Comment: Yes - exactly. So first win is, it TS will help you providing what keys are available. Secondly, it will give you errors trying to put in invalid keys whereas it wont if I go with the "strigified" index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I have not found a way to completely avoid creating a javascript function to solve this (also told that might not be possible at all, at this moment), I have found what I believe is an acceptable solution:

```js
type GameInfo = { [key: string]: { skillLevel: 'good' | 'average' | 'bad' }}

type EnforceObjectType<T> = <V extends T>(v: V) => V;
const enforceObjectType: EnforceObjectType<GameInfo> = v => v;

const GAMES2 = enforceObjectType({
  CSGO: {
    skillLevel: 'good',
  },
  WOW: {
    skillLevel: 'average'
  },
  DOTA: {
    // Compile error - missing property skillLevel
  }
});

type GameKey2 = keyof typeof GAMES2;

function getGameInfo2(key: GameKey2) {
  return GAMES2[key];
}

getGameInfo2('WOW');
getGameInfo2('CSGO');
getGameInfo2('unknown') // COMPILE ERROR HERE
```

This way we get:

1. Compile errors on missing properties.
2. Autocomplete of missing properties.
3. Able to extract the exact keys defined in the object, without having to define those elsewhere, e.g. in an enum (duplicating it).

I have updated [my Gist](https://gist.github.com/hilleer/521b4cbcebbf487f5023cd81e936f4d6) to include this example and you might be able to see it in practice on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=43&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4ghgWwgSQHYDMD2UC8UDeUA2gNYQgBcUAzsAE4CWqA5gLpWHUkMA2PAMhABuEHlQDkzTJgAm4qAB8o4uCLpxmEeUvEAjOHKgBfIwChToSFACiGTHQDGEAPK6AVhAfAAKuAgAebwA+XCh-ADUoCAAPYAhUGWooYIAKISpwgEpcEPCAblMHTFRaKLtHF3dPHz8qWywK1w8vX0h-eCQ0LBC8IRyoIQLC4tKYAEEAWWsAZQAmUPiGpybq1ogU-FMoKABhaZhnDi3tmm4+QRExZSlZcQAaY6MH7YB1Zxejk9PeAWFRCVUEHUmnEj2eUAAIs5vGNPicAPTw3aYBBgXjQIF0exQAC0UAQDGo1CYzCgYCxkDooG+5z+PEepiMmSGlmgHQgAGlyPM8GQQJh0FBWQLYJMZrMhugAK6oLwMYpQTTAdldTCzFJ8qjsrkgWbZTbbOgQYBSuioUVTOakcisApmUxKlV2dXiN4vcTMh3Gp1YF17A4egqOxAoZ0pcQykioTAAd1QHqgiN2zgmAAVkPxrDYAErZ5zZqAACWs2esQA).

Answer (score 3):

Hope this help you now:

```
enum EnumOfSkillLevels {
  Average = 'average',
  Good = 'good'
}

type GameObject<T extends { [key: string]: {skillLevel: EnumOfSkillLevels} }> = {
  [key in keyof T ]: {skillLevel: EnumOfSkillLevels}
}
const GAMES_OBJECT = {
   wow: { skillLevel: EnumOfSkillLevels.Average },
  csgo: { skillLevel: EnumOfSkillLevels.Good },
   lol: { skillLevel: EnumOfSkillLevels.Good }
} as const;


function getSkillLevel(key: keyof GameObject<typeof GAMES_OBJECT>) {
  return GAMES_OBJECT[key]
}

getSkillLevel('wow') // Does return wow object, but gives me no real-time TS help
getSkillLevel('lol') // Does return wow object, but gives me no real-time TS help
getSkillLevel('unknown') // Does give me a TS error
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=52#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-ocKCgAAtiHoaFrzsldWCsIaoCbzZbrZLpbL9Y7nbY3R6vWwfVaoP7A8HgKGI1HODH44nk5LtRddUS0IGtiAszmLTWq0Ra5wWA1Y7cmFImEA).

Comment: Thanks for your response. While I am totally aware of this solution, it is not the one I seek, as I have to create duplicates of each key. That is redundant and annoying if you have a long list of keys.

Comment: Is `GAMES_OBJECT` a fixed constant that you change manually, or it is a base object to create another?

Comment: It is in fact a frozen object (`Object.freeze`). I will extract and each use key of it, but not mutate anything. I will only add new keys harcoded.

Comment: This work for you? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEHkBmBlA1gSwDZYDLADdgsBnKAbwFgAoKKAQSICcBDAc2CgF4oByF5u2C8ANDToBxAPZSAJtz5sZs3jQC+NGgGMpIEgBcoE+gFkYKAPoIAQgCkYAYQAqCqrToB3KR4BcFKCSYOPhEWH5wkMjo2HiExCQAdIzArBxQamLuWiRKfuQBQbGh4fBRhSHxCdJy6Zl0UFhSYf6BMRXNEYio5XGkVcrp6lAsZDp6+gDcmtQ0SGAgWvoYulAc+tHBvQAUaMAAnn67e1JIUPp7AA7AJ0am5lZ2jk4AlBTiUEzA+mBMILdmlhs9mcAG0jgBddTTNYbIrELa8LweXivAD0qKgABEpMAyJ9vr8oEioFIAEYAK2AixEUFJYEMbAwRDIEE4ICkH2ALCwAFolqyoE4UFAABbEC40GE9UIIxpYFFQdFYnF4r4-P7EsmU6m0+mrJm4qAC9mc7l8jACoWi8WSr6w9oI+ZodkeEAKpXYw2MohGzgsQXClJMKRMIA

Comment: Yes, but I will have to add each key to both the enum and the object every time there is a new one, which is what I try to avoid to reduce complexity as this list might be growing rather big, eventually. 
I have added a gist to the original question of an example of how it should be.

Comment: No, I mean the new link I commented above. I removed the games enum

Comment: Ah, sorry - yes that is how I like it, although I want to define a general purpose type for all the objects of each key. That is a big part of my question - I believe I already achieved what you suggested in my example code. For my real world example, an enum would not work, as there will be many keys in each object....

Comment: I don't see how/where you add the type of the objects of each key in `GAMES_OBJECT`? I want to add the types to the object, so it disallows adding new entities without required properties. Does that make sense? We are pretty close, but it is not exactly the solution I'm looking for yet.

Comment: Ok, I see, but the `getSkillLevel` receives a param of type `GameObject<typeof GAMES_OBJECT>` and `GameObject` type needs a generic which extends the type you want, `extends { [key: string]: {skillLevel: EnumOfSkillLevels}`. So TS is gonna complain on the function, not in the object itself. It is a problem for you?

Comment: Nope, not really. I'd just really want to:
1. create a type the keys in the object, without having to define those elsewhere but in the object.
2. Add a type for each key in that object, so I make sure that they have required properties. 
3. If possible, avoid to wrap it inside a JavaScript function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Pedro. I believe it helped me in the direction of creating an acceptable solution that I have shared on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I write my codes in this way:

```
function define<T>(o:T){
  return o;
}
type Node = {
  value: number,
  key: string
}
const NODE_DIC = {
  LEFT: define<Node>({
    value: 1,
    key: '1'
  }),
  RIGHT: define<Node>({
    value: 2,
    // compile error for missing `key`
  })
}
```

Here is the type of the object:

```
{
    LEFT: Node;
    RIGHT: Node;
}
```

Comment: Why not just:
`LEFT: {...} as Node`
?